# Matlab file size different of the variable size in memory

Tags: matlab, file, variables, printf, size

I have the below code in Matlab, fg is an array of 1000x1000x1000 uint8. The final size of renato.raw is 1.190857E6 x 1024 instead of 1E9  (1000x1000x1000). Does any one know the reason?

```
    fid = fopen('renato.raw', 'w');
    fprintf(fid, '%u', fg);
    fclose(fid);
```

In case of:

```
    fid = fopen('renato.raw', 'w');
    fwrite(fid,fg,'uint8');
    fclose(fid);
```

In this case the file is 0.976563E6 x 1024. How to solve this issue? How to explain?

Thanks,

Luis Gonçalves

Answer (score 1):

`fprintf(fid, '%u', fg)` writes a *text* file with the contents of `fg`. For example, if `fg = [0 10 20 30]` the file contains the *text* `0102030` saved as 7 bytes in ASCII. That's why the size increases, depending on how many decimal figures the numbers in `fg` have.

`fwrite(fid, fg, 'uint8')` writes each value of `fg` directly as a byte. The file size in bytes should be the same as `numel(fg)`. Note that `0.976563E6 * 1024` is very approximately `1000*1000*1000` (perhaps that number `0.976563E6` has been displayed with some rounding).

Comment: You have right about last paragraph. I missed that.